# static ip on windows phone 8

Tags: settings, nokia-lumia-920, wifi, internet

Can I use static ip on wp8 ? In my office they use ip addresses over wifi network . If I want to connect through the wifi it requires to put **IP**,Subnet Mask,**Gateway** and **DNS Server**.
On **Android** or **iOS** we can easily put **IP** and **DNS**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any option to let you specify a static IP address on a Windows Phone client. A more secure option would be to use MAC filtering over the WiFi network, and assign the IPs to trusted MAC addresses (if you really need them to be static)

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: That would be a configuration change for your WiFi router.

Comment: Some routes call it 'Static DHCP' or 'DHCP Reservation' . Also, this 'issue' was not fixed for GDR2.